# Can't upload / update assets on Tumblr: "Something strange happened while saving that"

Tags: tumblr

When trying to upload or update any assets (javascript, css, images, anything) in the theme customization panel, we are receiving the following error message:

"Something strange happened while saving that. Please try again in a bit?"

This started happening about 16 hours ago, and we can't seem to avoid it. We have gone so far as to create new user accounts, with blogs created from scratch, but still receive the same error message when attempting to upload assets.

Any advice? We have contacted Tumblr customer support, so I will post their response here once I have it... But if anyone has some guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question can only be answered by Tumblr Support.

Answer (score 0):

Tumblr has confirmed the issue is on their end:

"Thank you for the additional information. Our engineers are aware and are currently working on a fix. I appreciate your patience as they get to the bottom of it."

I guess now we wait